# Python 3 when writing json file double backslash problem

Tags: python, json, regex, request

I use `urllib.request` and `regex` for `html parse` but when I write in `json` file there is double backslash in text. How can I replace one backslash?
I have looked at many solutions but none of them have worked.

```
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
req = Request('https://www.manga-tr.com/manga-list.html', headers=headers)
response = urlopen(req).read()
a = re.findall(r'<b><a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"',str(response))
sub_req = Request('https://www.manga-tr.com/'+a[3], headers=headers)
sub_response = urlopen(sub_req).read()
manga = {}
manga['manga'] = []
manga_subject = re.findall(r'<h3>Tan.xc4.xb1t.xc4.xb1m<.h3>[^<]*.n.t([^<]*).t',str(sub_response))
manga['manga'].append({'msubject': manga_subject })
with io.open('allmanga.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:
outfile.write(json.dumps(manga, indent=4))
```

this is my json file

```
{
    "manga": [
        {
            "msubject": [
                "  Minami Ria 16 ya\\xc5\\x9f\\xc4\\xb1ndad\\xc4\\xb1r. \\xc4\\xb0lk erkek arkada\\xc5\\x9f\\xc4\\xb1 sakatani jirou(16) ile yakla\\xc5\\x9f\\xc4\\xb1k 6 ayd\\xc4\\xb1r beraberdir. Herkes taraf\\xc4\\xb1ndan \\xc3\\xa7ifte kumru olarak g\\xc3\\xb6r\\xc3\\xbclmelerine ra\\xc4\\x9fmen ili\\xc5\\x9fkilerinde %1\\'lik bir eksiklik vard\\xc4\\xb1r. Bu eksikli\\xc4\\x9fi tamamlayabilecekler mi?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you `print(repr(manga_subject))` to find out what the text is? As a note, it looks like you’re writing a web scraper. I would recommend, in general, using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead of regular expressions. But it is your choice.

Comment: It also looks like the code is trying to match the Turkish word “Tanıtım”. However, `r'<h3>Tan.xc4.xb1t.xc4.xb1m'` is incorrect. You can either type `r'<h3>Tanıtım'` or you can use `'Tan\u0131t\u0131m'`. The string `b'\xc4\xb1'` is just `'ı'.encode('UTF-8')`, but in Python 3 you cannot use this, and `'.xc4'` would not match `'\xc4'` anyway.

Comment: I use repr but it is not worked and everything works perfect just double backslash is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why Is This Happening?

The error is when `str` is used to convert a `bytes` object to a `str`. This does not do the conversion in the desired way.

```
a = re.findall(r'<b><a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"',str(response))
#                                           ^^^
```

For example, if the response is the word "Tanıtım", you it would be expressed in UTF-8 as `b'Tan\xc4\xb1t\xc4\xb1m'`. If you then use `str` on that, you get:

```
In [1]: response = b'Tan\xc4\xb1t\xc4\xb1m'

In [2]: str(response)
Out[2]: "b'Tan\\xc4\\xb1t\\xc4\\xb1m'"
```

If you convert this to JSON, you'll see double backslashes (which are really just ordinary backslashes, encoded as JSON).

```
In [3]: import json

In [4]: print(json.dumps(str(response)))
"b'Tan\\xc4\\xb1t\\xc4\\xb1m'"
```

The correct way to convert a `bytes` object back to a `str` is by using the `decode` method, with the appropriate encoding:

```
In [5]: response.decode('UTF-8')
Out[5]: 'Tanıtım'
```

Note that the response is not valid UTF-8, unfortunately. The website operators appear to be serving corrupted data.

## Quick Fix

Replace every call to `str(response)` with `response.decode('UTF-8', 'replace')` and update the regular expressions to match.

```
a = re.findall(
    # "r" prefix to string is unnecessary
    '<b><a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"',
    response.decode('UTF-8', 'replace'))
sub_req = Request('https://www.manga-tr.com/'+a[3], 
                  headers=headers)
sub_response = urlopen(sub_req).read()
manga = {}
manga['manga'] = []
manga_subject = re.findall(
    # "r" prefix to string is unnecessary
    '<h3>Tanıtım</h3>([^<]*)',
    sub_response.decode('UTF-8', 'replace'))
manga['manga'].append({'msubject': manga_subject })
# io.open is the same as open
with open('allmanga.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    # json.dumps is unnecessary
    json.dump(manga, fp, indent=4)
```

## Better Fix

### Use "Requests"

The [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library is much easier than using `urlopen`. You will have to install it (with pip, apt, dnf, etc, whatever you use), it does not come with Python. It will look like this:

```
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.manga-tr.com/manga-list.html')
```

And then `response.text` contains the decoded string, you don't need to decode it yourself. Easier!

### Use BeautifulSoup

The [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library can search through HTML documents, and it is more reliable and easier to use than regular expressions. It also needs to be installed. You might use it like this, for example, to find all the summary from a manga page:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
subject = soup.find('h3', text='Tanıtım').next_sibling.string
```

### Summary

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/depp/a41ca728669888c085bc47b1397b4328) containing a more complete example of what the scraper might look like.

Keep in mind that scraping a website can be a bit difficult, just because you might scrape 100 pages and then suddenly discover that something is wrong with your scraper, or you are hitting the website too hard, or something crashes and fails and you need to start over. So scraping well often involves rate-limiting, saving progress and caching responses, and (ideally) parsing robots.txt.

But [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) + [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) will at least get you started. Again, see the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/depp/a41ca728669888c085bc47b1397b4328).

Comment: Thanks for awesome comment you saved my life :)